# What is the game on the Shrek DVD that allows you to rescue Fiona?

Tags: video-games, shrek

A while back, I asked a question on the Shrek Headscratchers page on TV Tropes and someone answered beginning with the following sentence:

> A game on the DVD only allows you to rescue Fiona.

What is this DVD game? How do you play it? Is it like the Dating Game parody that the Mirror does in Shrek? Is it on the 2 Disc DVD?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Sci-fi and Fantasy Stackexchange! While you're here, please take the [tour] and checkout the [help] to familiarise yourself with the way the site works.

Comment: I've noticed you edited your question with more details. In general you don't need to show your edits with 'Edit:' it's sufficient to just add data, and the website keeps a log of all changes. If you have an answer to your own question, you're encouraged to post it as a separate answer (using the answer text box below).

Answer (score 7):

The game is on the bonus disc of the 2 disc *Shrek* DVD. The game is called "Rescue the Princess." It is not like the dating game; it is more like the scene where Shrek actually goes up the tower to rescue the princess. Here is a video of the walkthrough:

and here is a picture of the title screen: [image: and here is a picture of the title screen]

Comment: Is it on all versions of the Shrek DVD? or just the Two-disk special editions?